# how to add a scrollbar to raphael object ,for example,a rect object

Tags: scroll, scrollbar, raphael

In my Raphael paper,  a rect object is larger than my paper width, How to add a scrollbar to this rect object .
For example:

```
var paper = new Raphael("holder", 500, 400);

var rect = paper.rect(100, 100, 1000, 1000);
```

What i want to do is ,Inside the paper, add a ScrollBar component to this rect  but not this paper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try this,

```
<div id="holder">
  <div id="rectangle-holder">
  </div>
</div>

var paper = new Raphael("holder", 500,400);
var rectangleHolder  = new Raphael("rectangle-holder", 200,200);
var rectangle = rectangleHolder.rectangle(100,100,1000,1000);
```

Using CSS add scrolllbar to `rectangle-holder` div